# error when i type 'npm start' to conect my website with localhost

Tags: node.js, json, linux, npm, sudo

I'm trying to start a web page, but when i type npm start in the terminal(in folders proyect) shows me an error.

```
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/dmarin/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dmarin/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dmarin/.npm/_logs/2020-02-20T16_05_39_782Z-debug.log
```

am connected to a mysql database in localhost , using php admin with apache.Your help will be more than great full.

Comment: Do you have a package.json?

Comment: you seems to have forgot to `cd` into the app directory, the error says that you are at `/home/dmarin` directory, which I guess is your OS user home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use npm to start your server, which then will serve web pages, then you will need to do `npm init`, it will create pacakage.json

It will look something like this:

```
  > npm init --yes
  Wrote to /home/ag_dubs/my_package/package.json:

  {
    "name": "my_package",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package.git"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
      "url": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package"
  }
```

npm start looks for pacakage.json file or pacakage-lock.json file.
and will launch the file that you mention in pacakage.json.

In the above file, it will look for:

**"main": "index.js"**

so all you need to do is replace index.js with the webpage you want.